# How to use dev:module entry point in infernojs npm package

Tags: typescript, webpack, infernojs

I'm using inferno js with typescript (using ts-loader and transformInferno in webpack3) and mostly it's working well. However when running within the webpack-dev-server inferno outputs `You are running production build of Inferno in development mode. Use dev:module entry point.` in the browser conosole.

Whilst I can see that inferno has a `dev:module` entry defined in the package.json I don't understand how to use this entry point rather than the default `module`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registering an alias in webpack should do the trick. Like this:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'inferno': 'inferno/dist/index.dev.esm.js',
    },
},
```

You can then add a condition to point to the non-dev one if you are running in production mode or not.

Comment: on rollup use alias plugin

Comment: Use this to choose between dev and prod ->
`'inferno': (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') ? 'inferno/dist/index.dev.esm.js' : 'inferno/dist/index.esm.js'`

Comment: It's not clear where this should be used. Please indicate which files to use it in.